# "--keep-going" turns a fatal build into a successful build

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Errors.html#Errors):***

> Normally `make` gives up immediately in this circumstance, returning
>   a nonzero status.  However, if the `-k` or `--keep-going` flag is
>   specified, `make` continues to consider the other prerequisites of the
>   pending targets, remaking them if necessary, **before it gives up and
>   returns nonzero status**.  For example, after an error in compiling one
>   object file, `make -k` will continue compiling other object files even
>   though it already knows that linking them will be impossible.  *Note
>   Summary of Options: Options Summary.

In other words, `--keep-going` does not imply that Make will ***totally ignore*** the errors AND return with *exit-status = 0*.

On the contrary, it means that Make will ***temporarily suspend*** the errors, and continue only with other **independent builds** (i.e. builds that do not depend on this failing target). Yet it will ***eventually*** "restore" those errors, and fail accordingly.

***But, consider the makefile:***

```make
# If 'd' was a "regular" file, we remove it first.
$(shell rm -rf D)
# Force make to do a "direcotry-serach(a "vpathization")", for the file 'all'.
$(shell rm -rf all)
# 'D' is a VPATH directory
$(shell mkdir D)
# Make will associate 'all' with 'D/all'
$(shell touch D/all)


VPATH = D


root: all;

# Building 'all' results in a fatal error.
all ::
    false

.SILENT: D/all
```

***Executing, we get:***

```console
# The "normal" case (without '--keep-going').
$ make -j
makefile:15: recipe for target 'D/all' failed
make: *** [D/all] Error 1

$ echo 'exit-status is: '"'$?'"
exit-status is: '2'

##########################

# Run with '--keep-going'
$ make -j -k
makefile:15: recipe for target 'D/all' failed
make: *** [D/all] Error 1

$ echo 'exit-status is: '"'$?'"
exit-status is: '0'
```

The build fails, as the prerequisite had failed to build. Yet Make returns ***successfully*** for the second run, where we had the `-k` (`--keep-going`).

Make passes on a failing (and incomplete) build, as though it was a successful build.

Is this the expected behavior or are there some errors with the example above?

Answer (score 3):

When `--keep-going` is used, the exit code returned is the exit code of the last target status.  Target "all" fails, but since you want to keep going, target "root" continues and that succeeds.

Run

```
 make -j -k all || echo failure
```

And you'll see that just building "all" will give a nonzero exit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is the expected behavior. To workaround this one would run

```
$ make -j -k
$ make -j 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

1. Run make as far as possible. Log all errors.
2. Stop on error (with exit code), do not print errors (they would be repeated from (1)).

The second run should be very short, since everything else is built. And it will set the correct exit status.